# Symfony with DDEV CLI db connection

Tags: docker, symfony, ddev

I want to start a Symfony Project using docker !
I tried to build it using DDEV CLI!
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/cli-usage/

I used the standard configuration from DDEV. (php)

As soon as I want to make:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

I got :

```
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: 
  getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

.env file:

```
 DATABASE_URL="mysql://db:db@db:3306/db?serverVersion=10.2"
```

When I change the host to : 127.0.0.1 in .env:

```
 DATABASE_URL="mysql://db:db@127.0.0.1:3306/db?serverVersion=10.2"
```

I got:

```
   An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested 
   authentication method unknown to the client
```

DDEV config.yaml

```
  name: bib
  type: php
  docroot: public
  php_version: "7.3"
  webserver_type: nginx-fpm
  router_http_port: "80"
  router_https_port: "443"
  xdebug_enabled: false
  additional_hostnames: []
  additional_fqdns: []
  provider: default
  use_dns_when_possible: true
```

Kindly ask for help in this Regards.

Comment: Please share more details - how **exactly** do you call `php bin/console`? From **within** the ddev container?

Comment: @NicoHaase I missed that ! If I run **php bin/console** inside (DDEV ssh) works fine!
I think this answer my question ! Everything is working fine using db as host!
Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run all such commands from **within** the ddev container, either through a SSH terminal (`ddev ssh` opens a shell in the container), or as an ad-hoc command (`ddev exec php bin/console make:migration`).

This is needed because the hostnames used to communicate between one container and any other are only resolve from within the containers itself